# How can I create an EGL context from a native function when the NativeWindowType is created in a Java SurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to create the EGL context to draw everything with OpenglES within a native function call. The problem is that I need access to the NativeWindowType instance, but I could only find a function to create one (which I can't find out how to link, anyway). However, even if I create one, I suspect that would be wrong, since what I really need is the one created by the SurfaceView instance from which I'm calling this native function.

Here is the code:

```
static int egl_init() {

const EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
};
EGLint w, h, dummy, format;
EGLint egl_major_version, egl_minor_version;
EGLint numConfigs;
EGLConfig egl_config;
EGLSurface egl_surface;
EGLContext egl_context;

EGLDisplay egl_display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

// v--------- This is where I should get the display window
NativeWindowType display_window;
display_window = android_createDisplaySurface();

eglInitialize(egl_display, &egl_major_version, &egl_minor_version);
printf("GL Version: %d.%d\n", egl_major_version, egl_minor_version);

if (!eglChooseConfig(egl_display, attribs, &egl_config, 1, &numConfigs))
{
  printf("eglChooseConfig failed\n");
  if (egl_context == 0) printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
}

eglGetConfigAttrib(egl_display, egl_config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

// v---------- This requires that I link libandroid, it is found in android/native_window.h
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(display_window, 0, 0, format);

egl_context = eglCreateContext(egl_display, egl_config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
if (egl_context == 0) LOGE("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());

egl_surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(egl_display, egl_config, display_window, NULL);
if (egl_surface == 0) LOGE("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());

if (eglMakeCurrent(egl_display, egl_surface, egl_surface, egl_context) == EGL_FALSE) {
    LOGE("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use android_createDisplaySurface().  It's not a public API, and it only works on devices that support the old framebuffer HAL (none of the recent Nexus devices support it).

Answer (score 2):

The surface can not support the the requested egl config (red,green and blue being at least 8 bits).

```
const EGLint attribs[] = { 
                EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_NONE
};
```

Some phones, makes all surface buffers RGB_565 by default.

In Java to get more detailed colors or alpha you can getWindow and setFormat(). Like so:
 getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
To do something equivalent in a native-activity you must do something like the following.

```
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(display_window, 0, 0, 1);
```

as defined in android/native_window.h

```
/*
 * Pixel formats that a window can use.
 */
enum {
        WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888           = 1,
        WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBX_8888           = 2,
        WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565                   = 4,
};
```

Hope this helps. I've seen this question around and I just figured it out.